# Configuring Azure for Django/Python 3

Tags: python, django, azure, python-3.x, azure-web-app-service

I had a Django project that uses python 3.2+. Having been through a couple Azure classes I wanted to deploy my Django application through Windows Azure. I got the web site synced through my Git Repository, and following the advice of the MSDN forums, added the python 33 runtime in a folder called /PythonCore/ and added WSCGI.py to the scripts folder within there.

My website can''t find the CGI interface and likewise is failing to process HTTP requests. I know something must be wrong in my configuration, but I havn't a clue as to what. I was wondering if anyone might know what my error is.

```
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 0.10.5
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  DjangoApplication.settings
PYTHONPATH              D:\home\site\wwwroot\DjangoApplication;
WSGI_HANDLER            django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler

Handler Mappings
*      D:\home\site\wwwroot\PythonCore\python.exe  D:\home\site\wwwroot\PythonCore\scripts\wfastcgi.py
```

Please let me know if any additional information is needed or you have an idea what I can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Web Sites w Django currently requires Python version 2.7.  Please see this:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-app-with-django-and-mysql/

and

http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Django%20Web%20Site/Cloud%20Service%20Tutorial

Corresponding video walk thru:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7A7VNnsA_8

Python 3.x will be supported soon (hopefully fall 2013).

Comment: The Azure team tried having me use a test version of the WCGI handler but it still failed. I guess I'm going to have to find another provider

Comment: It's past fall 2013 and it seems like there's still no support (azure beginner). Are there any official information about the Python 3.4 support?

Comment: It is working now:
put `python-3.4` in `runtime.txt` at the root of the project.
See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/